# Android Studio not installing particular application in particular device

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

Okay i have this strange situation... I have a project in android studio that was working fine till last night but when i uninstalled the application and made clean and rerun attempt to install the app it takes forever to install the app

Now the situation is i have other projects in android studio which i tried to run in the same device and they are installing fine. So i think the device is good.

I tried to run the same project on other device and it worked completely fine so i think the android studio as well as my code is fine.

i thought the uninstalling was the issue so i cleared cached data of device and it dint work. So anyone having idea how to resolve this issue?

I have tried everything like clean and rerun, invalidate cache and restart etc so suggest something else. Tell me if you want something from the code.

**Edit** :
Now I changed the package name of the project so that if the previous app gave some problem during uninstalling then it should treat this app as new application because i changed the package name but still it isn't working.

Comment: fyi i am using android studio version 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually i found the error due to which the android studio was taking forever to install the apk... it was not able to allocate memory during run time. This was the error i was getting.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 191692812 byte allocation with 12539072 free bytes and 110MB until OOM
                                                   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:613)
                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:446)
                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2771)
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2472)
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2370)
                                                   at com.miui.internal.variable.v21.Android_Content_Res_Resources_class.handleLoadDrawable(SourceFile:40)
                                                   at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:776)
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:742)
                                                   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:743)
                                                   at android.app.MiuiThemeHelper.getDrawable(MiuiThemeHelper.java:103)
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:157)
                                                   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:800)
                                                   at com.miui.permcenter.install.AdbInstallActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5982)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove it from other users as well if any exists in your device.

Comment: Try rebooting device once

Comment: have tried rebooting. it didn't work...no errors run window does not go ahead of pm command

Comment: got the solution it was not able to allocate memory during runtime... i tried to search for errors but the android monitor was not on NO Filters so i couldn't see the error...Thanks for your help though.